# JQuery only changing first instance

Tags: jquery

I have some code that will find the height of a div with the class name `.tab-content-header` and then change the `line-height` of the h1 inside of that div. It works for the first instance of `.tab-content-header h1`, but I have several instances and would like to change the line-height of all of them at the same time. All of them should always be the same. How can I alter my code to accomplish this? I tried using `.each()`, but things were getting messy and not working. Below is the JQuery I currently have and one instance of `.tab-content-header h1` so you can see what the markup looks like.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var $tabContentHeader = $('.tab-content-header');
    var $headerLineHeight = $tabContentHeader.height() + 10 + 'px';
    $tabContentHeader.find('h1').css({'line-height': $headerLineHeight});
});

<div class="row tab-content-header">
    <img src="images/content-area/page-header.png" class="img-responsive" alt="a1">
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: I ran your demo here, and It's working as expected. Try to open your console to see if you are missing some syntax or messing up with something.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working copy

http://jsfiddle.net/m330147x/1/

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    console.log("Start");
    var $tabContentHeader = $('.tab-content-header');
    console.log("Found " + $tabContentHeader.length + " Headers");

    var $headerLineHeight = $tabContentHeader.height() + 10 + 'px';

    var $h1 = $tabContentHeader.find('h1');
    console.log("Found " + $tabContentHeader.length + " h1");
    $h1.css({'line-height': $headerLineHeight});
    console.log("Finish");
});
```

View the developer console for debug info.  It should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $('.tab-content-header > h1').each(function(i, obj) {
        var headerHeight =  $('.tab-content-header').height() + 10;
        obj.style.lineHeight = headerHeight + "px";
    });
});
```

See working example: https://jsfiddle.net/g73uv468/